# Duration of exceedance of a threshold

Tags: probability

I dont know why there is not that much work in this regard, it should be a very well-established issue!

Assumptions: 
There is a time series of one random variable.Its auto-correlation, power spectral density could be driven numerically.

Question: 
What is the probability of exceedance above a certain threshold.

Probability($\tau$>duration of exceedance|H)=$F(\tau;H)=?$

$\tau$ is the exceedance duration for a given threshold H.

I do appreciate any comments or reference in this regard.